# How to use TerriaJS in a Rails Application?

Tags: cesium

I am looking to install TerriaJS as a Cesium/Leaflet replacement for the geospatial piece I have running on my web application. I have looked at Github and the wiki with the TerriaJS application and I don't see a clear path as to how to install and use TerriaJS with my application.

With leaflet it's fairly easy... add a reference to the .js file and the .css file, create a div... and bob's your uncle. However, I don't see that clear path with TerriaJS. It almost looks as if TerriaJS is meant to run as a nodejs application. I see where Nationalmap has used gulp (browserify) to turn it into a running web application, however, I need to do a lot of development. I went through the examples... I cloned the repo from github, but I don't see what exactly I am "browserifying".

Does anyone know of a tutorial or a plain-English example as to how to use TerriaJS inside of a Rails (or the like) web application?